# Using double quotes in xsl:param in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I would like to use double quotes in my XSLT, but I am getting error:

```
<xsl:param name="unsorted-values" as="xs:string*" 
    select=" 'Test 1','Test 1 with quote 21"' "/>
```

Obviously it is not working like this, because of double quote in the string. I tried to escape like `'Test 1 with quote 21\"'`, but it is not worked. Is there any way to use double quote in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of an XML attribute delimited by double quotes you can use the entity reference `&quot;` (or the appropriate numeric character reference).

Inside of an XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 string literal delimited by single quotes you can use two single quotes e.g. `''''` to have a single quote inside. Or if the string literal delimiter are double quotes you can double them inside e.g. `""""` to have a string with a double quote.

A complete example with various options is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="s1" as="xs:string*"
    select="'string with single quote: ''', 
             &quot;string with double quote: &quot;&quot;&quot;,
             'string delimited by single quotes with single quote: '' and double quote: &quot;',
             &quot;string delimited by double quotes with single quote: ' and double quote: &quot;&quot;&quot;"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="$s1" separator="&#10;"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputting

```
<root>string with single quote: '
string with double quote: "
string delimited by single quotes with single quote: ' and double quote: "
string delimited by double quotes with single quote: ' and double quote: "</root>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2U